# How do I specify disk size for new machine instance for Azure?

Tags: azure

I want to create a new NC6 instance (for my GPU and ML works). Few days ago I created my first instance for the NC6 instance, it was 150 GB standard SSD one, it was too much for me, so I tried to change the disk to low price one, but I noticed you cannot shrink or swap/change the disk to reduced size one or HDD one. So, I ended up deleting the instance and now trying to create a new one, but here, seems there is no way to change disk size, it seems you can change "OS disk type" to SSD to HDD, but no disk size e.g. 150 GB to 32 GB. So, How do I specify disk size for new machine instance for Azure? Thanks.

[image: https://yuis.xsrv.jp/images/ss/ShareX_ScreenShot_f2220036-99c5-49c1-abad-ee0caf8c4bd3.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change or specify your instance's disk size on Azure. The disk size for the OS disk is depends on the VM image.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/default-size-images-changed-30-gb